# Swift : Fetch action on tap on UILabel at specific position

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've a label shown in screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

When user taps on `Terms and condition` text of UILabel it should be able to **redirect to new view controller.**

There are few concerns:

1. **Redirect should happen on when** `Terms and condition` text region is tapped. Not on other text.
2. `Terms and condition` **can come different lines** (in case of iPhone 4)

How can this be acheived?

Comment: Use `UIButton` for the `Terms Of Use`.

Comment: Why not to use two different labels with one being touchable?

Comment: Well i guess you will need to add 2 Labels, one with text "I understand and accept the" and second  "Terms of Use". Then the label two, enable its user interaction and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064687/adding-tapgesturerecognizer-to-uilabel-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`.

Then you can use the  `AttributedString` to create hyperlinks inside `UITextView` and catch them using `UITextViewDelegate` to perform segues.

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320297/3207979) are more details about this approach